# Проблемы с передачей данных через точку доступа на телефоне

Tags: сервер, сеть

я написал приложение, которое отправляет сообщение на сервер и т.п., на локалхосте, через роутер и lan кабель все хорошо, но при подключении к точке доступа wify телефона (любого) приложение отсылает пакет, но он не приходит в точку назначения. IP указывал те, которые выдаются устройством Android, причем такая ситуация уже с несколькими телефонами, в чем может быть проблема и как ее избежать?
Телефоны Android, IP ввожу из командной строки компьютера, на котором включен мой сервер (подчеркну МОЙ),

Comment: 1. Сервер тоже на телефоне и где-то еще? 2. * > IP указывал те, которые выдаются устройством Android* - чей именно IP и где вы указывали?

Comment: Вообще добавьте в вопрос больше информации. Какая ОС на телефоне, какие конкретно адреса вы использовали - все, что сможет помочь.